How can I define the GIS locations of agents in anylogic?
I have a population of agents living in the main agent. These agents have two parameters using Latitude and Longitude, which is defined by uniform(... , ...) on startup code in agent.
Now, once longitude and latitude are defined, I need to set this point on the GIS Map.
I have tried using the function setLonLat(Latitude, Longitude) but its not working.
Need help!


As usual: pls do the step-by-step tutorials as they cover this and many more beginner concepts. See https://anylogic.help/tutorials/gis/index.html

Sir, Thanks. But for this specific case, i really need to specify the location of agents from inside the agent and not use any features like database, GISPoints, and so on. Can you please give me insight on this.

understood, pls always add such details ;) (i.e. what you tried already or what you do not need)

As per the API, setLanLon does not change the agent position at runtime:

Instead, use jumpTo():


Not really working.
The GISMAP is on Main agent, the population is on main agent. And I dont really need to change the location, I just need to initialize those agent location. But I am not sure why its not working. Even jumpTo is not working.

then you call it wrongly. Try with a simple example model: 1 GIS map, 1 agent, simple button that make it jumpTo. You will see it works. Then, apply to your model accordingly. If you do not know how to navigate through your model, study https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

Yes, you are correct. Something was wrong with that specific model. I created a new model and tried both jumpTo and setLatLon, both seems to be working.
